# Program freezes when writing to a file Java

Tags: java

So, I have this assignment to read the text from one file and write to another, changing all the text to uppercase. I'm not sure why, but when I run it, it freezes after I enter the file to write to. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class McKinneyBenjaminUpperFile
{
   public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Benjamin's Uppercase File Converter\n");

      String file1;
      String file2;

      System.out.println("Enter the name of the file to read from.");
      file1 = keyboard.nextLine();

      File file1open = new File(file1);

      if(!file1open.exists())
      {
         System.out.println("The file you entered does not exists.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      Scanner infile = new Scanner(file1);

      System.out.println("Enter the name of the file to write to: ");
      file2 = keyboard.nextLine();

      File file2open = new File(file2);

      if(file2open.exists())
      {
         System.out.println("The file you entered already exists.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(file2);

      while(infile.hasNext())
      {
         for(int i=0;i<file2open.length();i++)
         {
            String line = infile.nextLine().substring(0,1);
            String newLine = line.toUpperCase();
            outfile.println(newLine);
         }
      }

      System.out.println("Conversion complete. " + file1 + " is now converted to all uppercase in " + file2);
   }
}
```

Comment: where are you giving the file path?

Comment: I was unaware I needed to, and I'm not sure how to do that. I have some C++ experience, but files in Java appear to be entirely different

Comment: I don't really understand the intent of your code, but it looks like you never enter the for loop, since `file2open.length()` is always zero. As such, you are never consuming anything from `infile`, so `infile.hasNext()` continues to evaluate to true.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I didn't notice it at all. Truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but when I run it, it freezes after I enter the file to write to

In this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < file2open.length(); i++) { ... }
```

`file2open.length()` will return 0 since you have not created the destination file yet. See also [File.length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()):

> **Returns:**
>   The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist.

Hence the loop will never get executed. This results in `infile.nextLine()` never being called, hence your outer `while` loop will loop forever since `hasNext()` will continously return `true`.

Note that a `File` is only a representation of the File's meta data (like name and attributes). To write to a file, use a stream or writer class, like `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: So now, I'm having an issue with substring. i only included it so that my string line would read in one character at a time, but I'm not sure how to get the rest of the file to read in.

Comment: That's because you read the whole line and then only uppercase the first letter of it. Remove the substring part entirely and just uppercase the line `i.e. line.toUpperCase()`

Comment: You probably should give a concrete example of what you actually want to achieve - do you want **each** character be upper case, or only the first character of each line?

Answer (score 2):

It is your while and for loop

```
 while(infile.hasNext())
  {
     for(int i=0;i<file2open.length();i++)
     {
        String line = infile.nextLine().substring(0,1);
        String newLine = line.toUpperCase();
        outfile.println(newLine);
     }
  }
```

file2open.length() is to blame because .length() returns the length of the file denoted by the abstract pathname. Since it is a long, I assume it is doing some crazy calculations and the reason why your program freezes is because it is actually just doing a lot of calculations and still running. Nevertheless...

This would be a better way to covert:

```
  while(infile.hasNextLine())
  {
        String line = infile.nextLine();
        String newLine = line.toUpperCase();
        outfile.println(newLine);
  }
```

There is no reason to do individual substrings.

EDIT: Didn't read code correctly so the .length is in fact returning 0. But regardless, the .length is doing something different that what you think I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just tried this and got this error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at McKinneyBenjaminUpperFile.main(McKinneyBenjaminUpperFile.java:45)"

Comment: @MicroBM Actually I would not even use a `Scanner` to read the source file - use a `BufferedReader` and its `readLine()` method. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java

Comment: Haven't learned about BufferedReader yet. The professor for the class has briefly touched on files, but nothing too in depth @AndreasFester

Comment: Sorry should be:
    file.hasNextLine()